# How do I get the (x,y) coordinates from every data object in a plot?

Tags: r, plot, coordinates, igraph

I have a network (a graph), called netW, that I plot using Fruchterman-Reingold layout algorithm:

```
plot(netW, layout=layout_with_fr(netBanco, dim=3))
```

Now, I need to know the coordinates (3D) of every node in that plot. Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you make a small reproducible example? Including whatever packages you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually created that when you created the layout. Try this:

```
library(igraph)
LO = layout_with_fr(netBanco, dim=3)
plot(netW, layout=LO)
LO
```